# flutter want call parent view upon its child to refresh main view

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Stateful widget that has a child buttons and set of stateful containers (visible and invisible).
I want to try here is when i call the specific button, the specific button will refresh all layout and change it on its specifict view by setting visible while the others are not visible.

like this:

```
button1 = view1;
button2 = view2;
button3 = view3;

if (button1 is pressed){
view1 is visible}
 else{
not visible}
```

upon my code, upon my first view(login button),I've set to go with my main_page like this:

```
child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage(change1: true,change2: false,change3: false,)),
          );
        },

now i was display my main_page view (with a child view  that has visibility property).
```

this is my code on main_page:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool change1 ;
  final bool change2;
  final bool change3 ;

  const MainPage({Key key, this.change1,this.change2,this.change3}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();

}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                height: 280.0,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: new DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.blueAccent, BlendMode.colorBurn),
                  image: new ExactAssetImage("images/vector.jpg"),
                ),
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                print("i pressed Official Business");

                                 MainPage(change1: true,change2: false,change3: false);
                                  //TODO: here is my problem, when i call the main_page on its page,
                                //        the value of change1, change2, and chaange3 is not updating
                                 //       so that icanot update my view .

                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Official Business",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                print("i pressed file an OB");
                                 MainPage(change1: false,change2: true,change3: false);

                                //TODO: here is my problem, when i call the main_page on its page,
                                //        the value of change1, change2, and chaange3 is not updating
                                 //       so that icanot update my view .

                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50.0,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "File an OB",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
            //TODO:
            new Visibility(
              //Called changed and viewOne
              visible: widget.change1,
              child: OfficialBusiness(),
            ),
            new Visibility(
              //Called not changed and viewTwo
              visible: widget.change2,
              child: FilingOb(),
            ),
            new Visibility(
              //Called not changed and viewTwo
              visible: widget.change3,
              child: ViewOfficialBusiness(),
            )


     ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

the fillingob/officialbusiness/ViewOfficialBusiness includded was set of stateful layout, i didn't add the code to prevent over views.

sorry, in new on this programming language and i've like to enlighten with these problems i've encountered if my code is possible or not.Also if you need more reference just ping on comment so that i can provide my other codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  bool change1;
  bool change2;
  bool change3;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    change1 = widget.change1;
    change2 = widget.change2;
    change3 = widget.change3;
  }

  void setChange1() {
    setState(() {
      change1 = true;
      change2 = change3 = false;
    });
  }

// GestureDetector(onTap: setChange1)

// Visibility(
//   visible: change1,
//   child: OfficialBusiness(),
// )
```

Or use enum :

```
enum MyView {
  officialBusiness,
  filingOb,
  viewOfficialBusiness,
}
```

```
MyView current;

// GestureDetector(onTap: () => setState(() { current = MyView.officialBusiness; }))

// Visibility(
//   visible: current == MyView.officialBusiness,
//   child: OfficialBusiness(),
// )
```

Comment: actually, i was implemented this but not in the initState() so that my widget.data cannot recognize the  vallues.. probably this is the answer . thank you.. also how's the enum works? do you  have any tutorial there so that ai can use it too..  :)

Comment: I posted `enum` in the answer.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, the standard way to call functions on a parent widget when something occurs in one of its children would be to pass a function from the parent widget to the child, so that the function gets triggered from the child, with data that only the parent widget knows.

In your case, in your first view, you could define a new method like this:

```dart
void onChildPressed() {
    setState(() {
       // Here you change the boolean change1, change2, whatever you want   
    });
}
```

And then, in the child view, you have to define a function parameter, such that your child can receive the function as a parameter, and trigger it from wherever you want in your child widget.

```dart
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool change1 ;
  final bool change2;
  final bool change3 ;
  final void Function() onPressed;

  const MainPage({Key key, this.change1,this.change2,this.change3, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();

}
```

This way, you can instantiate the `MainPage` from your first view like this:

```dart
MainPage(change1: false,change2: true,change3: false, onPressed: onChildPressed);
```

And, finally, you can call the `onPressed` function in your `MainPage`, so that your child view updates the parent view the way you want.

Comment: yeah, actually, on my gesture detector, upon "on-tap" has a setState() that calling the main page, upon my result the print value was appearing on my log cat and  calls again the main page but unfortunately  the setted value on change1,change2, and change3 is not getting the updated bool data, but the last state upon my login bool data was get.